# How to use sonar pmd permalink in maven-pmd plugin using m2e-code-quality?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube, pmd

I want to use my sonar PMD configuration using the permalink,

This is the build part of my maven pom.xml

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>http://nemo.sonarqube.org/profiles/export?format=pmd&amp;language=java&amp;name=Nemo</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pmd</id>
                    <goals><goal>check</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But when i import this into my eclipse (using the [m2e-code-quality](https://github.com/m2e-code-quality/m2e-code-quality) plugin), I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find the class White space is
>   required between the public identifier and the system identifier.

How can i fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try use older version of pmd plugin.

Version **2.7.1** works ok for me with external link.

Here is issue for this error:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPMD-174

Comment: Note that the issue was created by myself :-)

Comment: True - I didn't pay attention who created it. Sorry.